# Calculating a cubic spline goes wrong

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, spline

I am trying to solve a old exam and really stuck at the cubic splines.

We have the function $f(x) = \cos^2(\frac{x}{2})$  and the points $x_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $x_1=0$ and $x_2 = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

With some simple math we get the points:

$(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{1}{2}),(0,1),(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

The splines have the form:
$$ p_i(x) = a_i + b_i(x-x_i) + c_i(x-x_i)^2 + d_i(x-x_i)^3$$

So we get the $a_i$ simply by $a_i = y_i$.

some formulae that are needed

$$
\begin{align}
h_i &= x_{i+1} - x_i\\
b_i &= \frac{1}{h_i}(a_{i+1}-a_i) - \frac{h_i}{3}(c_{i+1}+2c_i)\\
d_i &= \frac{1}{3h_i}(c_{i+1}-ci)\\
c_1 &= 0, \ \ c_n=0
\end{align}$$

So next step for the calculation is to get the $c_i$ out of $Ac=r$ 
with 
$$ 
A=\left[
2(h_1+h_2) \dots
\right] 
$$
Since we just got 3 points it is an $1\times 1$ matrix (else it would be bigger). So I calculated the matrix $A=(2\pi)$ since $h_1 = h_2 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ with 
$$
r = \frac{3}{h_2}(a_3-a_2)-\frac{3}{h1}(a_2-a_1) 
$$

Out of this we get that $c_2 = -\frac{2}{3}$ if I am not wrong. And now we can calculate the left over coefficients.
$$
\begin{align}
b_1 &= \frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{9\pi}{8} \\
b_2 &= -\frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{18\pi}{8} \\
d_1 &= -\frac{6}{12\pi}\\
d_2 &= \frac{6}{12\pi}
\end{align}
$$

BUT the splines are not correct. For example for the first interval I get
$$
p_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{9\pi}{8})(x-\frac{\pi}{2}) - \frac{6}{12\pi}(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^3\\
p_2(x) = \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{1}{\pi} + \frac{9\pi}{8})(x-0) - \frac{6}{12\pi}(x-0)^3
 $$

**So what have i done wrong?** Most of the stuff is just using  formulae but I don't get the right solution out of it. 
In the end thanks for reading this long post!

Comment: Why do you have $(x-1/2)$ and $(x-1)^3$ there? The $x$-coordinates of given interpolation points are $\pi/2$ and $0$.

Comment: Yes thats right i inserted the wrong values here. Corrected it. But the output is still not correct.  As espected after seeing your answer.

Comment: You numbers are still out of place. When putting $x=0$ into $p_2$ I get $1/2$, which should be $1$. So the constant term is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that the mistake I pointed out in a comment will help to straighten out the computation. Meanwhile, let me present a different approach, which may be more illuminating that "put these numbers into these formulas".

The given data points are symmetric about the $y$-axis. So will be the spline. In particular, the spline will have derivative zero at $x=0$. By symmetry, we only need to find it on the interval $[-\pi/2,0]$.

First, find the **piecewise linear** function through given points: on the interval $[-\pi/2,0]$ it is $l(x)=1+x/\pi$. On the whole interval the piecewise linear interpolant looks like this.

[image: pl]

Second, look for the **cubic correction** term $c(x)$, which must be zero at the nodes of interpolation, have zero second derivative at $-\pi/2$, and have derivative $-1/\pi$ at $x=0$ (to cancel out the slope of linear term, which creates a corner on the plot above). It is convenient to use Taylor form at $-\pi/2$, in the following fashion: 
$$c(x) = a\left(\frac{2}{\pi}x + 1\right)^3 + b\left(\frac{2}{\pi}x + 1\right)$$
This choice simplifies the algebra. Indeed, $c(0)=0$ implies $b=-a$ and $c'(0)=-1/\pi$ yields
$$ 3\frac{2}{\pi}a - \frac{2}{\pi}a = -\frac{1}{\pi}$$
hence $a=-1/4$.

Final result: for $-\pi/2\le x\le 0$ the spline is 
$$
p(x) = 1+\frac{1}{\pi}x - \frac14 \left(\frac{2}{\pi}x + 1\right)^3 + \frac14\left(\frac{2}{\pi}x + 1\right)
$$
On the other interval it's symmetric: $p(x)=p(-x)$.

Here is the plot of piecewise linear interpolant (blue), cubic correction term (red), and their sum  (black), which is the desired spline.

[image: spline]

Derivation from basic principles is generally more enlightening than mimicking a spline-generating computer routine.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! Could you explain a bit more how to get the cubic correction therm? Maybe a litle bit more generally?

Comment: @BennX I wrote about this [here](http://calculus7.org/2014/02/14/connecting-dots-naturally/) and then another blogger [generalized](http://thalestriangles.blogspot.com/2014/02/a-bit-of-ex-spline-ation.html).

Comment: Thanks alot! Yea my numbers are somehow totally incorrect. I dont find where i made the mistake of the formulae but okay. Your solution and the blog entry will sure help me to understand and to solve tasks like this. Thanks for the time and affort.

Comment: @BennX You can still try to fix your computation. I think part of the problem is inconsistent enumeration of data points: you used $0$ for $x$ and $1/2$ for $y$ in one formula. There are three data points, but only two polinomial pieces of spline; easy to make fencepost errors.

Comment: yea true but it is always confusing me that the calculation somehow starts at different enumeration than usual and i dont get that straight. Regular we start at $x_0$ and the computation uses $x_1$ to start. Id love to see a whole calculation with that algorithm but somehow i just find "short" forms of it which does not explain enough for me.